# Android Hotspot internet connection comes and goes

Tags: wifi-hotspot, xiaomi

When I'm connected to my android hotspot from my laptop, internet connection
comes and goes every few minutes. It happens both on Windows and Ubuntu so that I think the problem is not from receiver side.

Phone: Xiaomi A1 
OS: Android 8

If I remember correctly, it used to be ok in the past. I'm not sure, but maybe it started when I updated to Android 8. Maybe!

Comment: When this is happening, is the internet connection on the phone itself OK, or does that also drop out every few minutes?

Comment: Good question. I should have mentioned that. The weird part is that the internet connection is fine on phone while problem happens in the connected laptop.